# Strictly-increasing functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)>x+\delta$ for $\delta>0$.

Tags: functions

Function $f(x): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has the following two properties.

1. $f(x) > x + \delta$ with $\delta > 0$;
2. $f(x)$ is strictly increasing, i.e., $f(x_1) > f(x_2)$ for $x_1 > x_2$.

In addition to the examples $f(x) = x + \delta$ with $\delta > 0$ where the coefficient of $x$ is 1, are there any other examples?

Comment: How about $f(x) = e^x + \delta$?

Comment: Take any strictly increasing function $g$ with $g(x)>x$ for all $x$, and let $f(x)=x+\delta$. Or any strictly increasing function $h$ with $h(x)>0$ for all $x$, and let $f(x)=h(x)+x+\delta$.